# Web Speech API Digits only

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I am writing a web application which requires me to recognize spoken digits. I am using the javascript Web Speech API. It is working quite well at the moment, but I'd love to restrict the recognition to digits only, to improve the accuracy. One thought I've had is to set the grammar, but I cannot for the life of me work out how. Is anybody aware of a way to make this restriction?

Comment: We recently used the Web Speech Api.We added validation using simple Java Script.Do you want to do something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speech Grammar could be a way to do this but it is not yet supported by any browser. http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/ .For the time being you have to use a javaScript function like isDigits()